# How to get the properties of an image in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to figure out the dimensions of an image along with its type in a script so I can pre-set the length and width of my plot window. How can I do that using Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Julia images are simply arrays. Just use `size(img)` full code below:

```
using Images
#requires using Pkg;pkg"add ImageMagikck"
img = load("photo.jpg")
```

Now get the size:

```
julia> typeof(img)
Array{RGB{Normed{UInt8,8}},2}

julia> size(img)
(2222, 2396)
```

If you want to display the image:

```
using ImageView
imshow(img)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without reading the image into memory?

Comment: The dimensions are in file's headers so I guess this should be possible. Maybe `ImageMagikck.magickinfo()`?

Comment: Thanks, that was a good starting point. The method I'm using is `ImageMagick.metadata`, which appears to return a 2-tuple `((width, height), color_info)`

Comment: @BallpointBen, did you call your ImageMagick command within your Julia script? If so, what command did you use?